# Replace the suffix of a string ending in '.js' but not 'min.js' with a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

Assume `infile` is a variable holding the name of an input file, and similarly outfile for output file.  If infile ends in `.js`, I'd like to replace with `.min.js` and that's easy enough.

```
outfile = re.sub(r'\b.js$', '.min.js', infile)
```

But my question is if `infile` ends in `.min.js`, then I do not want the substitution to take place.  (Otherwise, I'll end up with `.min.min.js`.)

How can I accomplish this by using a regular expression?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to do a negative lookbehind assertion. For instance,

```
outfile = re.sub(r"(?<!\.min)\.js$", ".min.js", infile)
```

You can find more about this here: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: Just what I was going to say.

Answer (score 3):

For tasks this simple, there's no need for regexps. String methods can be more readable, eg.:

```
if filename.endswith('.js') and not filename.endswith('.min.js'):
    filename= filename[:-3]+'.min.js'
```

Comment: yep, I knew that, but the question provides a good chance for me to learn more about regex.